# detailed information for each entry in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

So i have made a Web Form with a dropdownlist which contains different classes in school and if you select one you get all the students of the selected class in the GridView below. So what i want to make now is, that if i click on a student it should open a more detailed page about the student, but i have no clues how to do this. I get all my data of a .mdf database file.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="schueler.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPXUebung.schueler" %>
```

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selectklassen" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1klassenselect" DataTextField="K_Bez" DataValueField="K_ID" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1klassenselect" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [K_Bez], [K_ID] FROM [klassen] ORDER BY [K_Bez]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="S_SCHNR" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1schueler">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_SCHNR" HeaderText="S_SCHNR" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="S_SCHNR" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Name" HeaderText="S_Name" SortExpression="S_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Vorname" HeaderText="S_Vorname" SortExpression="S_Vorname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Gebdat" HeaderText="S_Gebdat" SortExpression="S_Gebdat" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Adresse" HeaderText="S_Adresse" SortExpression="S_Adresse" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_K_Klasse" HeaderText="S_K_Klasse" SortExpression="S_K_Klasse" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1schueler" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [schueler] WHERE [S_SCHNR] = @original_S_SCHNR AND (([S_Name] = @original_S_Name) OR ([S_Name] IS NULL AND @original_S_Name IS NULL)) AND (([S_Vorname] = @original_S_Vorname) OR ([S_Vorname] IS NULL AND @original_S_Vorname IS NULL)) AND (([S_Gebdat] = @original_S_Gebdat) OR ([S_Gebdat] IS NULL AND @original_S_Gebdat IS NULL)) AND (([S_Adresse] = @original_S_Adresse) OR ([S_Adresse] IS NULL AND @original_S_Adresse IS NULL)) AND (([S_K_Klasse] = @original_S_K_Klasse) OR ([S_K_Klasse] IS NULL AND @original_S_K_Klasse IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [schueler] ([S_SCHNR], [S_Name], [S_Vorname], [S_Gebdat], [S_Adresse], [S_K_Klasse]) VALUES (@S_SCHNR, @S_Name, @S_Vorname, @S_Gebdat, @S_Adresse, @S_K_Klasse)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [schueler] WHERE ([S_K_Klasse] = @S_K_Klasse)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [schueler] SET [S_Name] = @S_Name, [S_Vorname] = @S_Vorname, [S_Gebdat] = @S_Gebdat, [S_Adresse] = @S_Adresse, [S_K_Klasse] = @S_K_Klasse WHERE [S_SCHNR] = @original_S_SCHNR AND (([S_Name] = @original_S_Name) OR ([S_Name] IS NULL AND @original_S_Name IS NULL)) AND (([S_Vorname] = @original_S_Vorname) OR ([S_Vorname] IS NULL AND @original_S_Vorname IS NULL)) AND (([S_Gebdat] = @original_S_Gebdat) OR ([S_Gebdat] IS NULL AND @original_S_Gebdat IS NULL)) AND (([S_Adresse] = @original_S_Adresse) OR ([S_Adresse] IS NULL AND @original_S_Adresse IS NULL)) AND (([S_K_Klasse] = @original_S_K_Klasse) OR ([S_K_Klasse] IS NULL AND @original_S_K_Klasse IS NULL))">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_SCHNR" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Vorname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Gebdat" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Adresse" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_K_Klasse" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_SCHNR" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Vorname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Gebdat" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Adresse" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_K_Klasse" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="selectklassen" Name="S_K_Klasse" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Vorname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Gebdat" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_Adresse" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="S_K_Klasse" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_SCHNR" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Vorname" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Gebdat" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_Adresse" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_S_K_Klasse" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: This sounds and looks a lot like a school project...

Answer (score 0):

Make the student name column a Hyperlink column like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="S_SCHNR" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1schueler">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="S_SCHNR"
          DataNavigateUrlFormatString="StudentInfo.aspx?id={0}
          DataTextField="S_Name" "/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_SCHNR" HeaderText="S_SCHNR" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="S_SCHNR" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Name" HeaderText="S_Name" SortExpression="S_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Vorname" HeaderText="S_Vorname" SortExpression="S_Vorname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Gebdat" HeaderText="S_Gebdat" SortExpression="S_Gebdat" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_Adresse" HeaderText="S_Adresse" SortExpression="S_Adresse" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="S_K_Klasse" HeaderText="S_K_Klasse" SortExpression="S_K_Klasse" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Make another web page called StudentInfo.aspx. On that page, display the data using a DetailsView control, a SqlDataSource control and the QueryString parameter.  Here's an example of how to do that: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient way to do this without creating a new page would be to populate the data into a Bootstrap modal like [this](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/0f1b65c3-b0f6-4a93-b4b5-56c278d855c2/?Editable%20Grid%20View%20System%20using%20BootStrap%20in%20ASP%20Net). It uses UpdatePanel, which may or may not be something you want to use though.

1. Add the Detail Event to the Gridview.
2. Create a div for the Bootstrap modal with a FormView
3. Call the jQuery from the C# code behind to populate the data in the FormView with the ID from the GridView.